# Writing image file names within folders into a text file c++

Tags: c++, file-io, input, output

I wrote a little bit of code to easily add the file names of images i had within a directory and add them to a list in a text file. This worked fine, but when the images were within a sub-folder it would just add the folder name as an entry into the text file.

I need it to be able to check whether it's a folder and then add the correct directory into the text for the images which might be within the sub-folder, e.g subfolder/image.jpg

Can't work out what i'd need to add. This is what I've got so far...

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
#include<fstream>
#include<dirent.h>

void listFile();

std::ofstream myfile;

int main(){
listFile();
return 0;
}

void listFile(){
    DIR *pDIR;
    struct dirent *entry;
    if( pDIR=opendir("/home/hduser/Example2Files/TrainImages/") ){
            while(entry = readdir(pDIR)){
               if( strcmp(entry->d_name, ".") != 0 && strcmp(entry->d_name, "..") != 0 )

               myfile.open ("/home/hduser/Example2Files/TrainImages/train.txt",std::ios_base::app);
               myfile << entry->d_name << "\n";
               myfile.close();

            }
            closedir(pDIR);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to make `listFile` a recursive function.  Make it take a single parameter that is the name of the directory the be read.  Then you can just call it on any directories you encounter.

Answer (score 1):

To traverse into directories, you will (probably) have to modify your code such that you have a function that takes the name of a directory, and lists regular files within that directory. If it finds a directory, it should call recursively with the concatenated name of the current directory and the found directory.

To identify if the file is a directory, you can use something like `entry.d_type == DT_DIR`.

Comment: I've managed to add some code so that it detects whether it's a directory and then goes into another function. However i'm having a bit of trouble passing over the correct directory name of the directory it has stopped on. 

Also i'm not quite sure how i'd then recursively go through that directory listing the files.

Comment: You'll need a local variable to hold the new directory name (of size PATH_MAX), which is made from appending the newly found directory to the current input to the function. Then call back into the function with the new path. Simple string manipulation, really.